# Can we still save/update production apex trigger code using API?

Tags: security

As we know we can update the production class using API.

I am just trying to update one of my production trigger using eclipse.

This is not getting saved instead it is showing other test class error.

Is there any security added by Salesforce while updating class or trigger using API.

Comment: Another test class fails during deployment. Is it related to your trigger? Are you also trying to deploy it or just the trigger? Are you deploying the trigger's test class at the same time? Is your total code coverage in production above 75%?

Comment: @crmprogdev Trigger is already deployed to Production with test class.. I am just  to update one single line of code using Eclipse.. I can again upload a changset and deploy the latest code.. But I curious why I am unable to save trigger using Eclipse..

Comment: @crmprogdev While updating production trigger from API (Eclipse).. total code coverage required ? If yes then may be this is issue. One of our new client there org code coverage is really bad.. I need to work so much to fix this..

Comment: Yes total coverage is still required when updating any existing code. If total coverage has gone down, you won't be able to update your trigger until you bring your code coverage back up to 75% overall. It's also always wise to deploy the test class with your code even if it hasn't changed. Eclipse will usually recognize that, but at least will know the class is there.

Comment: @crmprogdev ohh Now it make sense to me.. Thanks for info.. Please add as answer so I can accept the ans and close this question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

75% total code coverage is still required when updating any of your existing code. Salesforce considers updates to existing code as "new code".

So, if your total coverage is below 75%, you won't be able to update your trigger until you bring your overall code coverage back to at least 75% by increasing the coverage of other test classes. It's also always wise to deploy the test class with your code even if it hasn't changed. Eclipse will usually recognize that, but at least it will know the class is there.

Answer (score 0):

No. I just test this and I can save the Trigger in Production. I think in your class there is some test class exception (Eg: Some one created a new validation rule for required field) and there are many other reason (Newly created Required field).

So I suggest you to check these scenario and your problem will be solved.

```
Note: I test this on 2 devices(API V35, V29)
```

Comment: Tushar No For me it is not working. My trigger API is v28.. Event If i try to update to 29 still not updating.. I am using Keplar eclipse and it is upgraded with v 36.